# Remove Radio Button Icon In Split View Windows Universal Apps

Tags: c#, windows, c#-4.0, win-universal-app

I want to remove the radio button icon when creating a split view in windows 10 apps.I have attached the screenshot of the current view of the stack panel.Is this function can be done through the design view of the visual studio? 
[image: I have attached the screen shot of the current view of the stack panel]

XAML Code `

```
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="Narrow">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MySplitView.DisplayMode" Value="Overlay" />
                    <Setter Target="MySplitView.IsPaneOpen" Value="False" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Compact">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MySplitView.DisplayMode" Value="CompactOverlay" />
                    <Setter Target="MySplitView.IsPaneOpen" Value="False" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Wide">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1024"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MySplitView.DisplayMode" Value="CompactInline" />
                    <Setter Target="MySplitView.IsPaneOpen" Value="True" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <SplitView x:Name="MySplitView" DisplayMode="Inline" IsPaneOpen="True">
        <SplitView.PaneBackground>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="WhiteSmoke" Opacity="0.4" />
        </SplitView.PaneBackground>

        <SplitView.Pane>
            <StackPanel Margin="0,30,0,0">
                <RadioButton Tag="Map" Click="RadioButtonPaneItem_Click">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Map" Foreground="Black" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Map" Margin="15,0,0,0" Foreground="Black" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </RadioButton>
                <RadioButton Tag="Mail" Click="RadioButtonPaneItem_Click">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Mail" Foreground="Black" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Mail" Margin="15,0,0,0" Foreground="Black" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </RadioButton>
                <RadioButton Tag="AddFriend" Click="RadioButtonPaneItem_Click">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="AddFriend" Foreground="Black" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Add a Friend" Margin="15,0,0,0" Foreground="Black" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </RadioButton>
                <RadioButton Tag="aaaa" Margin="4,0,0,0" >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Accept" Foreground="Black" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Add a Friend" Margin="15,0,0,0" Foreground="Black" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </RadioButton>

                <RadioButton Tag="Settings" Click="RadioButtonPaneItem_Click">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Setting" Foreground="White" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Settings" Margin="15,0,0,0" Foreground="White" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </RadioButton>
            </StackPanel>
        </SplitView.Pane>

        <Frame x:Name="MainFrame" />
    </SplitView>
    <Button x:Name="HamburgerButton" Width="{Binding ElementName=MySplitView, Path=CompactPaneLength}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="HamburgerButton_Click">
        <StackPanel>
            <Rectangle Width="15" Height="2" Margin="2" Fill="White" />
            <Rectangle Width="15" Height="2" Margin="2" Fill="White" />
            <Rectangle Width="15" Height="2" Margin="2" Fill="White" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

`

Comment: One way is to apply the ToggleButton style to the RadioButton. If you search, there are several good posts about it.

Comment: Thank you. I found the toggle button style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the way to remove the radio button icon

1. Go to properties of the radio button in visual studio
2. Miscellaneous properties
3. Set Style to "System Resources" > "Text Block Button Style"
   [image: Here it is]